# non-null object become empty json

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying write web application with spring boot, but found the object returned from controller method become empty json, hers is my code:

**Application.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application {
    @Bean
    public DataSource ds() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("test");
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(ds());
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("hello");
        return lef;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
        CustomerRepository repository = context.getBean(CustomerRepository.class);
    }

}
```

**Customer.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    protected Customer() {}

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }

}
```

**MyController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Customer> getAll() {
        return (List<Customer>) customerRepository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Customer findOne(@PathVariable long id) {
        Customer customer = customerRepository.findOne(id);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println(customer);
        return customer;
    }
}
```

I can see the customer printed in the console, so I guess the data access is working, the only problem is why the customer object is converted to empty json.

[image]

Comment: First of all try it after removing `@EnableWebMvc`. Unless you have so Spring MVC configuration that you have not shown, that annotation would override the Spring Boot defaults.

Comment: I've removed the @EnableWebMvc, but it still not work.

Comment: And you are sure that Customer is not null?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't you need some public getters?

Comment: Forgetting simple things is easy. I just did it ;)